# getElementById trouble

Tags: javascript

html: `[...]<div id="test" name="testvalue"></div>[...]`

js`[...]alert(document.getElementById("test").name);[...]`

Why I get 'undefined' instead of 'testvalue'?

Comment: There is no `name` attribute for `<div>` elements. Start with [valid](http://validator.w3.org/) HTML before worrying about things not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `name` is not a valid attribute for a `<div>` element. As such, it doesn't map to the `.name` property.

You could probably get it using the `getAttribute()` method though:

```
alert(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("name"));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BcYXL/